# Searching for text in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the below URL and would like to extract prices. For that I load the page into beautifulsoup:

```
soup = bs(content, 'lxml')
for e in soup.find_all(class_="totalPrice"):
```

Now I get a text that looks like this (this is one single Element of type bs4.element.Tag):

```
<td class="totalPrice" colspan="3">
<div data-component="track" data-hash="OLNYSRfCbdWGffSRe" data-stage="1" data-track="view"></div>
Total: £145
</td>
```

How can I create another find expression that will extract the 145? Is there a way to search as for "Total" and then get the text just next to it?

[URL with original content that I extract](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-17CAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaFCIAQGYAS64AQTIAQTYAQHoAQH4AQs&sid=1a43e0952558ac0ad0061d5b6523a7bc&dcid=1&checkin_monthday=23;checkin_year_month=2016-1;checkout_monthday=24;checkout_year_month=2016-1;&city=-2601889&class_interval=1&csflt=%7B%7D&dtdisc=0&group_adults=7&group_children=0&highlighted_hotels=1192837&hlrd=0&hp_sbox=1&hyb_red=0&inac=0&label_click=undef&nflt=ht_id%3D201%3B&nha_red=0&no_rooms=1&redirected_from_city=0&redirected_from_landmark=0&redirected_from_region=0&review_score_group=empty&room1=A%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA&sb_price_type=total&score_min=0&si=ai%2Cco%2Cci%2Cre%2Cdi&ss=London&ss_all=0&ssafas=1&ssb=empty&sshis=0&ssne=London&ssne_untouched=London&order=price_for_two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex!

```
>>> import re
>>> search_text = 'blah Total: result'
>>> result = re.findall(r'Total: (.*)', search_text)
>>> result
['result']
```

If you want to be more general and capture anything that looks like currency, try this:

```
>>> result = re.findall(r': (£\d*)', search_text)
```

This will get you the currency symbol `£` + and of the following digits.

Comment: I like the regex approach. But is there a way to do an 'or' so I can search for multiple items? This doesn't work: p = re.findall(r'(Total: (.*))(Price for 1 night: (.*))',s)

Comment: Hmm, can you change it to just match on the currency? - see edit

Answer (score 1):

You can get text from tag

```
text = e.get_text()
```

and you have normal string `Total: £145` so you can split it

```
text.split(' ') # [`Total:',  '£145`]
```

slice it

```
text[8:]  # 145
```

use regular expression, etc.